# Linux as a USB UVC device

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, usb, uvc

What is needed for making a Linux device (Raspberry Pi) behave like a UVC device for another computer? Essentially, I would like to use output from ffmpeg to behave like a webcam input for another computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is needed for making a Linux device (Raspberry Pi) behave like a UVC device for another computer?

This can actually be done on the Pi Zero without a custom kernel. After setting `dtoverlay=dwc2` in your config.txt for OTG support, reboot and run:

```
sudo modprobe g_webcam
./uvc-gadget -d
```

These are first steps to make your Pi behave as a webcam by streaming synthetic data, which you can test out in Skype, FaceTime, or other webcam viewers. [Here](https://github.com/jdonald/uvc-gadget) is source for the uvc-gadget userspace program with its commonly recommended patches.

> Essentially, I would like to use output from ffmpeg to behave like a webcam input for another computer.

This part could be more involved. The existing uvc-gadget program can supposedly play back webcam recordings captured via GStreamer, more discussion on that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703234/how-to-create-mjpeg). For arbitrary input to FFmpeg, you may have to integrate your own output plugin code with uvc-gadget.

If you go as far as using compression: note FFmpeg can already output mjpeg in various container formats, but that data would still have to be converted to the UVC payload mjpeg format.

Answer (score -2):

You will roughly need an USB OTG capable RPi, the RPi 3 is not capable of that. 
Then you will need a custom kernel driver that emulates the UVC Driver of a real device, I am not aware of any project that does this directly.

The easiest way I can think of would be to stream the recorded images via RTMP instead of trying to emulate UVC as that is not a small feat.